# Criteria - Hibernate and webservice

Tags: web-services, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I tired from

```
public List<ListTimekeeping> findCreatedBy (String created_by) {
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(ListTimekeeping.class);      
    return cri.add(Restrictions.eq("created_by", created_by)).list();
}
```

and on webservice

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "findCreatedBy")
public List<ListTimekeeping> findCreatedBy(@WebParam(name = "created_by") String created_by) {
    ListTimeKeepingDao ltkd = new ListTimeKeepingDao();
    return ltkd.findCreatedBy(created_by);
}
```

with error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:342)
 at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106)
 at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:157)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:313) 
... 32 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: could not resolve property: created_by of: cl.model.pojos.ListTimekeeping Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
 at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy262.findCreatedBy(Unknown Source)
... 37 more
```

Sorry, I'm from Viet Nam and my English isn't good!

Comment: Code for this model class please `cl.model.pojos.ListTimekeeping`

Answer (score 0):

@Antoniossss

```
@Antoniossss : this code of cl.model.pojos.ListTimekeeping
```

package cl.model.pojos;

public class ListTimekeeping  implements java.io.Serializable {

```
 private Integer id;
 private String createdBy;
 private boolean isActive;
 private String name;
 private String code;

public ListTimekeeping() {
}

public ListTimekeeping(String createdBy, boolean isActive, String name, String code) {
   this.createdBy = createdBy;
   this.isActive = isActive;
   this.name = name;
   this.code = code;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCreatedBy() {
    return this.createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}
public boolean isIsActive() {
    return this.isActive;
}

public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCode() {
    return this.code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
```

}

Comment: okey, fixed :D,. in
i.add(Restrictions.eq("created_by", created_by)).list();
change created_by to createdBy :D